# Parent key not found (oracle)

Tags: oracle

I want to insert 400000 random lines into a table with an oracle procedure.

I got an 'violated - parent key not found' Error.

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE TESTDATA AS 
X INTEGER;
BEGIN
  FOR X IN 1..400000 LOOP
    INSERT INTO SALES 
    SELECT CAST(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 10) as INTEGER) as "CUSTOMER_ID",
    CAST(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 2) as INTEGER) as "PRODUCT_ID",
    TO_DATE(TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1-jan-2000'),'J'),TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('21-dec-2012'),'J'))),'J') as "SALES_DATE",
    CAST(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 100) as INTEGER) as "PIECES"
    FROM  DUAL;
  END LOOP;
END TESTDATA;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table SALES
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE SALES (
  CUSTOMER_ID INTEGER,
  PRODUCT_ID INTEGER,
  SALES_DATE DATE,
  PIECES INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, SALES_DATE),
  FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER (CUSTOMER_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCT_ID) REFERENCES PRODUCT (PRODUCT_ID)
);
```

I hope that anyone could help me.

Roman

[image: Table customer]

[image: Table product]

Comment: It means what it says: you are inserting values in either `customer_id`or `product_id` which do not have corresponding values in your `customer`or `product` table. Please provided their contents in your question.

Comment: In the customer table I have inserted 10 rows (1-10) and in the product table 2 rows (1-2).

Comment: It is not important how many records you have inserted, but which primary keys they have. Please add the table contents of these 2 tables in your question (edit it).

Comment: I have edited my post.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Can you provide a script that creates everything from scratch, and runs the procedure, and produces the error?

Comment: you should use `FORALL` instead of `FOR`. Other than this, did you make sure you committed the transaction where you inserted the customers and products?

Comment: The values your statement produces should be fine - they are integers between 1 and 10, and between 1 and 2, as they should be. @Sebas asks the right question - were the transactions committed? Other than that, your whole idea WILL FAIL, because you are trying to insert 400,000 rows, with `(customer_id, product_id, sales_date)` as primary key. But there are only 10 customers, 2 products and less than 4500 dates, to a max of 90,000 distinct values. Even if everything else worked, you would get a different kind of primary key violation - duplicate PK triples in the 400,000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Your `create table` statement includes foreign keys on the CUSTOMER and PRODUCT tables. Your insert statement uses random values to populate CUSTOMER_ID and PRODUCT_ID. It is highly unlikely that random values will match existing keys in the referenced tables, so it's unsurprising that you get foreign key violations.

As to how you fix it, well that depends on what you actually want to achieve. As you're populating your table with random numbers you clearly don't care about the data, so you might as well drop the foreign keys. Alternatively you can use primary key values from the referenced tables in the insert statement.

---

> "How can I use the primary key values from the referenced tables?"

You have twenty permutations of PRODUCT and CUSTOMER. So you will need to thrash through them 20000 times to generate 400000 records.

> "In the customer table I have inserted 10 rows (1-10) and in the product table 2 rows (1-2)"

Here's a version of your procedure which loops through Products and Customers to generate random combinations of them. There's a third outer loop which allows you to produce as many sets of twenty combos as your heart desires.

```
create or replace procedure testdata 
    ( p_iters in pls_integer := 1)
as 
  type sales_nt is table of sales%rowtype;
  recs sales_nt;
  rec sales%rowtype;
  tot_ins simple_integer := 0;
begin
  recs := new sales_nt();
  dbms_random.seed(val=>to_number(to_char(sysdate,'sssss')));
  << iterz >>
  for idx in 1..p_iters loop
    << prodz >>
    for c_rec in ( select customer_id from customer
                   order by dbms_random.value )
    loop
      << custz >>
      for p_rec in ( select product_id from product
                       order by dbms_random.value )
      loop
        rec.customer_id := c_rec.customer_id;
        rec.product_id := p_rec.product_id;
        rec.sales_date := date '2000-01-01' + dbms_random.value(1, 6000);
        rec.pieces := dbms_random.value(1, 100);
        recs.extend();
        recs(recs.count()) := rec;
      end loop custz;
    end loop prodz;
    forall idx in 1..recs.count()
      insert into sales
      values recs(idx);
    tot_ins := tot_ins + sql%rowcount;
    recs.delete();
  end loop iterz;
  dbms_output.put_line('test records generated = '||to_char(tot_ins));
end testdata;
/
```

Proof of the pudding:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec testdata(2)
test records generated = 40

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from sales;

CUSTOMER_ID PRODUCT_ID SALES_DAT     PIECES
----------- ---------- --------- ----------
          9          2 21-FEB-02         42
          9          1 10-AUG-05         63
          7          1 23-FEB-12         54
          7          2 21-NOV-12         80
          1          2 06-NOV-15         56
          1          1 08-DEC-09         47
          4          2 08-JUN-10         58
          4          1 19-FEB-09         43
          2          2 04-SEP-02         64
          2          1 09-SEP-15         69
          6          2 20-FEB-08         60

...

          2          1 11-JAN-16         19
          3          2 03-FEB-10         58
          3          1 25-JUL-10         66
          9          2 26-FEB-16         70
          9          1 15-MAY-14         90
          6          2 03-APR-05         60
          6          1 21-MAY-15         19

40 rows selected.

SQL>
```

### note

As @mathguy points out, the OP's code constrains the range of random values to fit the range of primary keys in the referenced tables. However, I will leave this answer in place because its general approach is both safer (guaranteed to always match a referenced primary key) and less brittle (can cope with inserting or deleting PRODUCT or CUSTOMER records.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I use the primary key values from the referenced tables?

Comment: @RomanStidl - The whole premise of this answer is incorrect. The statement in the original post does not insert random values. It inserts, for example, `cast(dbms_random.value(1, 10) as integer)`. The result is not a (completely) random value; it is always an integer between 1 and 10. And the corresponding parent table has primary keys between 1 and 10. The answer is much more likely along the lines of "yes, but perhaps you didn't commit the transactions to populate the parent tables."

Comment: @mathguy - when I made my original response the OP hadn't posted any details regarding their source data let alone actual data. Now they have and I guess you're right, and I have wasted my time answering the question. Thanks for rubbing it in with the down vote :)

Comment: The code was there from the beginning, and it takes literally 10 seconds of CAREFUL reading to see the code generates whole numbers between 1 and 10 and between 1 and 2 respectively, so that wasn't likely to be the issue. With that said: I had also added a comment to you, saying the whole idea of doing this in a procedure (rather than plain SQL) was an even worse thing than misunderstanding the meaning of the code. That's what the downvote was for.  (continued below)

Comment: Then after I re-read the original post and saw the OP himself was doing this in a procedure (for no reason), I deleted the comment - I thought I shouldn't blame you for not changing what the OP was doing (although I think you SHOULD have pointed that out), but it was too late to take back the downvote. Anyway, that is easily fixed - you can delete your answer!